# Any documentation for the XML format of TF.EXE's vc status command?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I am writing a script which will act on modified files in my TFVC (Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control) workspace.  I'm invoking `tf.exe vc status /format:xml` to get the list of changes, but I need to exclude deletes.  Is the XML format it returns documented?  I know I want to filter on the chg attribute of the PendingChange elements, and I could discover the value by deleting a file and seeing what it returns, but I suspect there may be other values that I should check for as well.  It would be much nicer to work off a documented canonical list rather than fixing the script each time it fails on a new value or combination I hadn't seen before.  Does the documentation or a schema definition exist?  (Neither of the two search engines I use led me to any.)

Comment: Your reply triggered me to think of the TFVC client library, which led me to what is probably the most official list available, given that the XML format doesn't have official documentation.  So it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the pending change types come from the enumeration Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ChangeType which is documented in the TFVC client API documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb170193%28v%3dvs.120%29.  Although it's not documentation of the XML format, it is the canonical list of the possible values.

As a side note, I ended up not being able to use the XML output for my script since it does not include new files (unless they have been specifically added, which in my scenario they are not) which I needed for my script.  (Since I didn't have time to code to the TFVC client library, I parsed the output from `tf vc status /format:brief`.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no such documentation available yet. The [pending change types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/develop-code-manage-pending-changes?view=azure-devops#use-the-pending-changes-page-to-manage-your-work) using mostly are as below:

[image]

I've tested the chg attribute of the PendingChange element in the XML file for the pending change type above, you may reference it:

```
PendingChange chg="Encoding Branch" 
PendingChange chg="Undelete"
PendingChange chg="Rename"
PendingChange chg="Edit"
PendingChange chg="Add Edit Encoding"
PendingChange chg="Edit Rollback"
PendingChange chg="Delete"
PendingChange chg="Edit Encoding"
```